# Create a sequence of numbers in two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

Given two numeric columns in a dataframe following a sequence:

```
df = data.frame(year=c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003),
                period=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1))
```

The rules for this dataframe is that every time the second column `period` reaches the maximum(which is 3 in this case) the first column `year` sums 1.

By means of a function or library, How would be possible to follow the sequence some steps ahead? , for example 3.

For the sake of clarity, the expected output for this sequence, the following 3 numbers in every column would be:

```
output = data.frame(year=c(2003,2003,2004),
                    period=c(2,3,1))
```

Comment: What does n steps ahead mean here? This is not clear.

Comment: N steps is a number that indicates how many steps we follow the sequence after the original data. i.e.: 1,2,3 -> if N = 3 the sequence should be 4,5,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependent on your data, you will have to fit a specific formula for a specific sequence, as there are infinitely many possible paths this sequence could take. Having said that, here is one not too pretty way to achieve your desired result.

```
df$time=seq_along(df$year)

n=6

mod=lm(year~time,data=df)
pre=round(predict(mod,data.frame(time=(nrow(df)+1):(nrow(df)+n))))
pre
   1    2    3    4    5    6 
2003 2003 2004 2004 2004 2005

mod2=lm(period~year+time,data=df)
predict(mod2,data.frame(year=pre,time=(nrow(df)+1):(nrow(df)+n)))
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 3 1 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your overall project, maybe you can just generate the data directly:

```
expand.grid(period = 1:3,
            year = 2000:2004)
```